# How to replace value from one column with value from another column in the same file

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file with thousands of lines and columns, two of the columns are IP1 and IP2. IP1 is always the same 192.168.100.1

*example.com,192.168.100.1,10.10.1.1,,5effd70e9d99b1acf,10,63,58,42,0,21,84055280,0
example2.com,192.168.100.1,10.10.1.50,,255b2l429c8f23ee,10,63,37,42,1,21,1451066297,0
example3.com,192.168.100.1,10.10.1.58,,589b7a5f8677b,11,68,37,42,1,20,1451066297,0

.............*

I want to replace the value of IP1 with value of IP2, and delete the value of IP2.

I tried this:

```
sed -i 's/192\.168\.100\.1/$(grep 192\.168\.100\.1 file | awk -F',' '{print $2}')/' file
```

The following error occured:
sed: -e expression #1, char 68: unterminated `s' command

Please help.

Comment: You should read the book Shell Scripting Recipes by Chris Johnson to learn the basics of sed, grep, awk and general shell scripting and then Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins if you're going to do any other text manipulation in UNIX in future.

Answer (score 1):

awk to the rescue! eliminate sed, this should do...

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{$2=$3;$3=""}1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

sed to the rescue! eliminate awk, this should do...

```
sed -i 's/192\.168\.100\.1,//' file
```

This `sed` command finds the string "192.168.100.1," and replace it by nothing.

`.` has a special meaning in a sed command, so it requires backslash. More info on the man pages.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.